# Blender 2.8: mirror leg and arm bones?

Tags: armature, bones

I have named my leg and arm bones with *.R. How to mirror them to the left side (with naming *.L)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just select all your bones in *Edit Mode* then <kbd>Right Click</kbd> > *Symetrize*.